# Outer continuity holds in finite measure but fails in $\sigma$-finite measure.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

In my probability class, my professor talked something about the Outer continuity. It is the following:

If $A_{i+1} \subseteq A_i$ for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$, and $A = \bigcap_{i \in \mathbb{N}A_i}$, then $P(A) = \lim_iP(A_i)$.

I saw and proved this before. But this time he asked us to find a counterexample which shows that this one might fail in $\sigma$-finite measure, instead of finite measure.

In office hour, he actually gave an answer to us, which is like this:

Let $P$ be the Lebesgue measure on the real line. Denote $A_n = (n, +\infty)$, then $P(A) = 0$ since $A = \emptyset$. However, $\lim_{n\to\infty}P(A_n) = +\infty$, thus $P(A) \not = \lim_{n\to\infty}P(A_n)$.

I have not really learned measure theory thoroughly, so I have some troubles to get the idea why $\lim_{n\to\infty}P(A_n) = +\infty$, but $P(A) = 0$ here. Can anyone explain this a little bit? Thanks so much!

Comment: What is the length of the line $(n,\infty)$? The limit of a constant is the constant itself.

Comment: @copper.hat Since n is fixed, I think the length is $+\infty$.

Comment: Correct, for any $n$ the length (measure in this case) is $+\infty$, hence the limit is $+\infty$. However, $\cap_n (n,\infty) = \emptyset$ and the measure of the empty set is $0$.

Comment: @copper.hat Thx so much for ur replying. I got the first part now. But can you explain a little bit more about why $\cap(n, \infty) = \emptyset$? My understanding is that if for any $n$ we have the length to be $\infty$, even in the case we take $n \to \infty$, then why would $\cap(n, \infty) = \emptyset$?

Comment: Because if $x\in \mathbb R$ then there is an $N\in \mathbb N$ s.t. $N>x$. Thus $x\notin (N,\infty )$ so $x\notin \cap(n, \infty)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(A_n)$ is the length of the interval $(n,\infty)$, which is infinity for each $n$. Thus $\lim P(A_n)=\infty$.

Suppose $x\in A$. There exists $N$ such that $x<N$. So $x\notin (N,\infty)=A_N$. This contradicts $x\in\bigcap A_n$. So in fact there is no element in $A$, i.e. $A$ is the empty set.